# How can I efficiently insert multiple form values into my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a long list of form values that I need to insert into my database. Rather than having a long list of bulky conditionals, is there an efficient way to insert all of these values into separate columns in my database?

Here's my code:

PHP:

```
// I've removed most of them to simplify demonstration
$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : "";
$how_hear = isset($_POST['how_hear']) ? $_POST['how_hear'] : "";

// I have to do this for every single form element:
if (!empty($title)) {
    DB::query('INSERT INTO `table` (`title`) VALUES (?);', array($title));
}
```

Comment: This all depends on what should happen if each of the fields is left blank? For example, if `$name` is blank presumably you don't want __any__ data written to the database? Where as if, for example, `$how_hear` is optional then it being left blank would be okay?

Comment: I've got javaScript form validation handling all of that. All I'm doing is inserting things if they aren't empty

Comment: So, if one is empty, then it should still continue to insert the others? In that case, you can just loop through the `$_POST` rather than explicitly writing out the conditionals for each item.

Comment: Ok thanks, how do I loop through the post? And also note that each column has a different name, so how am I supposed to insert values into different columns in a loop

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I have now added an answer down below that - I think - should do everything that you need!

Answer (score 0):

```
$usrData = array(
    "user" => "hello",
    "pass" => "pass1",
    "mail" => "test@email.com"
);

$cols = "";
$vals = "";
foreach($usrData as $col => $val) {
    $col = mysql_real_escape_string($col);
    $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);

    $cols.= "`{$col}`, ";
    $vals.= "'{$val}', ";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (". rtrim($cols, ", ") .") VALUES (". rtrim($vals, ", ") .");";   
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: if this is looping through each value, and your query is outside the loop doesn't that mean that the value is reset with every loop iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

```
$usrData = array(
    array(
        "user" => "hello",
        "pass" => "pass1",
        "mail" => "test@email.com"
    ),
    array(
        "user" => "user2",
        "pass" => "pass2",
        "mail" => "user2@email.com"
    )
);

$cols = "";
$bindQuery = "";
$i = 0;
foreach($usrData as $udata) {
    $vals = "";
    foreach($udata as $col => $val){    
        $col = mysql_real_escape_string($col);
        $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);

        $vals.= "'{$val}', ";

        if($i == 0)
            $cols.= "`{$col}`, ";       
    }
    $bindQuery.= "(" . rtrim($vals, ", ") . "), ";
    $i++;
}
echo $query = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (". rtrim($cols, ", ") .") VALUES ". rtrim($bindQuery, ", ") .";";   
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

- Database filed names and form field names are not the same.
- All data should be inserted into the same record in the database.
- All data should be entered into the database even if one or more fields is blank.

#### Example Post Data

The code below uses the following example data (as though it were sent from a site by the `POST` method) when outputting the example query.

```
$_POST["title"] = "Mr.";
$_POST["name"] = "Joe Bloggs";
$_POST["description"] = "Whatever it is this field is for, presumably some text...";
$_POST["how_hear"] = "google / search engine";
```

#### Code

```
$column_names = array( 
// Structure:           db-field-name   => form-field-name                        
                        "title"         => "title",
                        "customer_name" => "name",          // Example: Database field name would be "customer_name" and the form field name would be "name"
                        "content"       => "description",
                        "pointer"       => "how_hear"
                    ); 

$insert_columns = "";
$insert_values  = "";

foreach($column_names as $db_name=>$ws_name){ // Loop through fields specified in $column_names

    $value           = empty($_POST[$ws_name]) ? '' : $_POST[$ws_name];

    $insert_columns .= ", `".$db_name."`"; // Backticks to denote field names
    $insert_values  .= ", '".$value."'";   // Single quotes to denote values

}

// Generate the query
// substr function removes ", " from start of strings
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (".substr($insert_columns, 2).") VALUES (".substr($insert_values, 2).")";



echo $insert_query; // Show example output
// INSERT INTO `table_name` (`title`, `customer_name`, `content`, `pointer`) VALUES ('Mr.', 'Joe Bloggs', 'Whatever it is this field is for, presumably some text...', 'google / search engine')
```

**Quick Points**

- Shorthand `if` statments:

  ```
  $value = empty($_POST[$ws_name]) ? '' : $_POST[$ws_name];

  // Is equivalent to:

  if( empty($_POST[$ws_name]) ) {
      $value = "";
  }
  else {
      $value = $_POST[$ws_name];
  }
  ```
- The above code doesn't do anything to *sanitize* the input, so don't forget to sanitize the data etc.
- You can add as many fields to the `$column_names` array as necessary and the order is not relevant.
- I've used `echo` to show the query that the code generates as an example. You would obviously not do this... Instead you would pass the query `$insert_query` to your database connection. Something like:

  ```
  DB::query($insert_query);
  ```

  Of course this might (or rather: *would* )change depending on how you are connecting to the database...